# carriage return character in fsharp

Tags: f#

Why does a carriage return character not appear in a F# string literal bound like this

```
let hw = @"hello 
world";;
```

whereas in C# the following string does contain a carriage return character?

```
var s2 = @"hello
world";
```

Thanks

Comment: Wait.. I am confused. Are you asking why there is no carriage return in your F# example or why there is no carriage return in your c# example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it is quite easy to spot that the behavior of F# and C# *compilers* do not differ: being run thru FSC the following

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let s = @"Hello
world"
    printfn "%i" s.Length
    0
```

outputs `12` similarly to equivalent C# code.

What differs is, in fact, the treatment of multi-line string literals by `FSI`: sending lines 3-5 of the above snippet from VS to FSI with `Alt+Enter` produces output `11`, one less for absence of `carriage return` within the parsed string literal.

Came out this is a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7393658/917053), although I didn't manage to google the rationale behind this behavior.

Comment: It's not actually a problem with `fsi` itself, but with how VS sends text to it. If you run `fsi --exec file_with_crlf.fsx` from the command line, you will get 12.

Comment: @Tarmil: I just fired up `fsi v11.0.60610.1` from `cmd` and *typed in* lines 3-5 of the snippet above, getting output **11**, so VS seems standing out of the equation.

Comment: Try passing a file with --exec; I got 12. So probably the issue is processing files vs processing standard input.

Comment: @Tarmil: Well, `fsi --exec filecrlf.fsx` preserves `CRLF`s in the script file, while `fsi < filecrlf.fsx` swallows `CR`s from multi-line string constants in the same script file, indeed. This detail though does not add lots of value in addressing original concern, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code from the fsi and it entered the newline.

```
let hw = @"hello
world";;
printf "%s" hw;;
```

output

```
hello
world
```

Comment: hi Phil. thanks. this is correct. If you were to find the length of `hw`, it will be 11. It will contain a new-line character ('\010'). But not a carriage-return character ('\013'). But if you try my C# code, the resultant string will contain both new-line and carriage-return characters.

Comment: I see. I just tried both pieces of code from a proper F# console executable and from a c# console executable and they both return 12 characters. When I do the same code from fsi, it returns 11 characters. My conclusion, it is not the language that swallows it, but the F Sharp Interactive REPL mechanism.

Comment: To me, this is an FSI bug. It seems that the FSI developer hard-coded '\n' instead of using System.Environment.NewLine.